# Node express app.get("/.." parent directory not working

Tags: node.js, express

1. `./core/server.js`
2. `./core/index.html`
3. `./core/styles.css`
4. `./bin/init-transpiled.js`

How can I host `index.html` at `localhost:8000` (not `/core`) where `index.html` still has access to relative paths `../bin/init-transpiled` and `./styles.css`?

Answer (score 1):

You can host your index.html file like this.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + "/index.html"));
});
```

And you need to set bin folder as static folder in your server configuration to access bin folder files from client side.

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../bin')));
```

Then in index.html you can access your file like this.

```
<script src="../bin/init-transpiled.js">
```

Note that if index uses `./styles.css` for example, you would need to use `../core/styles.css`

Comment: Sorry about that, res.sendFile does not uses relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/../'));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
```

---

When `'/'` is used,

1. statically host this dir (for accessing local `./styles.css` for example)
2. statically host the parent dir (otherwise you can't traverse through `../bin/`)
3. send `index.html` as a response.

---

***Note:*** `'/'` is not required, the default is `'/'` and you can just write your middleware handler function as the first param

See [Express Docs - static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)